# exclude entries in MANIFEST.MF

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am currently building and EAR file using maven-ear-plugin

I have a requirement to exclude some of the Class-Path: entries from MANIFEST.MF file.

For example I have 3 dependencies hibernate-core.jar, quartz-1.6.5.jar and poi-3.7.jar in my class path (in my dependency of pom.xml)

When I build my EAR file all these entries will be automatically added to Class-Path entry of my MANIFEST.MF file.

My maven build looks as follows

```xml
<build>
    <finalName>MyEAR</finalName>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <addExtensions />
                    <classpathPrefix />
        </manifest>
                <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF               </manifestFile>
            </archive>
            .....
            .....
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

In the above build file

```xml
 <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
```

is responsible for adding the MANIFEST.MF entries.

My requirement is to add only 2 jars in dependency quartz-1.6.5.jar and poi-3.7.jar and exlcude the remaning.

If I give false all the entries are excluded from the MANIFEST.MF classpath.
If the remove the depependecy entries from pom I get compilation errors.

how can I achieve the above scenario.

thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Add scope "provided" to non-required dependencies:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>...</groupId>
            <artifactId>...</artifactId>
            <version>..</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there anyother way other than using provided scope? I am using maven-ejb-plugin to build my ejb jar. I am looking for something like applying filter/wild card filter under maven-ejb-plugin

Comment: Plugins "maven-ejb-plugin" and "maven-ear-plugin" have "manifestFile" option for custom manifest file.